# Forbid specific enum value for DTO in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

My "AppState" enum has following possible enum values:

```ts
export enum AppState {
  SUCCESS,
  ERROR,
  RUNNING
}
```

I have a *UpdateAppStateDTO* with an `appState` which should accept every enum value except *RUNNING*.

```ts
export class UpdateAppStateDTO {
  @IsEnum(AppState)
  @NotEquals(AppState.RUNNING) // Doesn't work properly
  public appState: AppState;
}
```

For the route I have this example

```ts
  @Patch()
  public setState(@Body() { appState }: UpdateAppStateDTO): void {
    console.log(appState);
  }
```

If the request has an empty body or a non valid enum value like "foobar" for `appState` I'm getting a 400, which is fine.

The problem is that when I send "RUNNING" I'm still getting a 200 instead of a 400.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I assume you are sending in the string `'RUNNING'`, and you're trying to make sure that that is what is not used, correct? With what you've currently got, your enum maps to these values:

```js
export enum AppState {
  SUCCESS = 0,
  ERROR = 1,
  RUNNING = 2
}
```

So if you send in the string `'RUNNING'`, the validator checks that `RUNNING !== 2` which is in fact `true` leading to successful validation. The `@IsEnum()` decorator checks that the value sent in in a valid key of the enum, so sending in `'RUNNING'` passes that check, hence why you don't get some sort of error there.

The most verbose way to fix this is to make your enum a `string enum` like so:

```js
export enum AppState {
  SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS',
  ERROR = 'ERROR',
  RUNNING = 'RUNNING'
}
```

This will make each `AppState` value map to its corresponding string, though that does lead to having to type out a lot of declarations and can lead to duplicate code.

Another way to manage this is to set your `@NotEquals()` enum to the key provided by the enum value like so:

```js
export class UpdateAppStateDTO {
  @IsEnum(AppState)
  @NotEquals(AppState[AppState.RUNNING])
  public appState: AppState;
}
```

But keep in mind that with this approach when you look at `appState` later it will still be a numeric value instead of a string.

You can play around with [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-irlmxs) I made for this to see some running code.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that when I send "RUNNING" I'm still getting a 200 instead of a 400.

it seems that you are using the string(!) "RUNNING" as value in your request payload as such:

```
{ appState: "RUNNING" }
```

In this case, `IsEnum` and `NotEquals` both regard the payload as valid.

**Why is that?**

First of all [numeric enums are reverse mapped by typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) so your enum is internally (as javascript object) represented as follows:

```
{
  '0': 'SUCCESS',
  '1': 'ERROR',
  '2': 'RUNNING',
  'SUCCESS': 0,
  'ERROR': 1,
  'RUNNING': 2
}
```

Now class-validator's `isEnum()` [is coded as follows](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/90a663866eaeb5a0cb38cce5501e0aa28984ed34/src/validation/Validator.ts#L416):

```
isEnum(value: unknown, entity: any): boolean {
    const enumValues = Object.keys(entity)
        .map(k => entity[k]);
    return enumValues.indexOf(value) >= 0;
}
```

and since the enum is reverse-mapped `isEnum('RUNNNING', AppState)` will return true.

At the same time `NotEquals`, which [is coded as such](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/90a663866eaeb5a0cb38cce5501e0aa28984ed34/src/validation/Validator.ts#L319)...

```
notEquals(value: unknown, comparison: unknown): boolean {
    return value !== comparison;
}
```

will compare the string 'RUNNING' against `AppState.RUNNING` (which equates to `2`) and also conclude that this is valid since `'RUNNING' != 2`.

So there you have it why the payload `{ appState: "RUNNING" }` will result in a 200 instead of a 400 status code.

> How can I prevent this behaviour?

The enum value `AppState.RUNNING` equates to `2` so when you make a request, you should use the numeric value of `2` in your payload:

```
{ appState: 2 }
```

In the above case, the class-validator's `NotEquals` validator will then correctly deny the request with the response containing:

```
"constraints": {
    "notEquals": "appState should not be equal to 2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can use enum in your DTO.**

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsEnum } from 'class-validator';

enum TYPE {
  SUPPORT = 'SUPPORT',
}

export class requestBody {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(TYPE)
  type: string;
}
```